# PHP PDO registration not working?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I know this is a very 'typical' question, it should be something so easy to do but I can't wrap my head around why it isn't working?, Once input is added to the form and 'enter' is hit, it simply redirects to register.php and echos 'connected succesfully' which is from my connect script. Nothing gets put into my database at all, any pointers where I'm going wrong would be great!

**HTML**

```
    <form method "POST" id="regform" action="register.php">
    <input type="text" username="username" placeholder="Please enter your 
    email"/>
    <input type="text" password="password" placeholder="Please create a 
    password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter"/>
    </form>
```

**Connect.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$dbname = "fyp";


try{
$pdostmt = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername, 
$dbpassword);
 $pdostmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo "connected succesfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print "Error! Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
// Starting the session and connecting to the DB
session_start();
require_once'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['register'])){


$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
$pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);


$stmt->execute();


$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($row['num'] > 0){
    die('That username already exists!');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, 
:password)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);

$result = $stmt->execute();

if($result){
    echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
            header("Location: index.php");
 }
    else {
        echo '<b> There has been an error please contact support </b>';
    }

}

?>
```

Been racking my brain over this for a while, any help would be appreciated and if i'm being stupid berate me.

Comment: In your queries, you should use `$pdostmt` instead of `$pdo` as it is your PDO object, `$pdo` is empty, though.

Comment: You haven't given names to any of your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `username="username"` to `name="username"` and `password="password"` to `name="password"` in your HTML.

You also need to check to see if `_POST['enter']` is set instead of `$_POST['register']` (thanks for the reminder Patrick Q).

And as Danielius points out, change `$pdo` to `$pdostmt` in register.php.

Comment: Definitely a change that needs to be made, but doesn't overcome the fact that `$_POST['register']` is what's being checked

Comment: Could you also write that the code will not work if `$pdo` is not switched into `$pdostmt` (or vice versa)? It is because `$pdostmt` is PDO object, but in prepared statements `$pdo` is being used.